# Excel Table Formatting Does Not Re-Apply After Refreshing Data From SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, excel-2013, vba

How would I force cell formatting to take effect automatically after a data refresh?

I have a connection set up to pull data from SQL Server to a table in Excel.

However, upon initial pull and refresh - cell formatting does not take effect on these cells, until I interact with them in some way such as double-clicking, or pressing F2, or even using `Text To Columns` to fix them all at once.

My settings indicate to preserve cell formatting, and it is preserved, it just doesn't seem to apply until interaction of some kind occurs.

[image: External Data Properties Settings]

See here before and after shots:

[image: Before Interaction]
[image: After Interaction]

The issue is affecting formatting of my entire table, the specific column shown IS a `date` type in SQL Server.

Is there something I'm completely overlooking to have cell formatting apply to cells after data refresh, or if this is just a bug in Excel, would it be possible to maybe macro out a `Text To Columns` action after every data refresh?

I'm on Excel 2013, with SQL Server 2008 R2.

Any help appreciated,
Thanks.

EDIT 1: No formulas exist in table, has been tested on multiple machines and on Excel 2013 and 2016 and issue still occurs.

Comment: Is there some sort of formula in those cells? Try: https://superuser.com/questions/836324/cells-not-updating-automatically

Comment: @justiceorjustus No formulas present in the table, it's just a straight pull from a database with the intent of formatting the date and a few other columns, as well as adding slicers and filters.

Comment: Try that and see if it helps.  Your issue feels like how an excel sheet behaves when that option turned off... I don't know if it affects formatting.

Comment: It was already automatic, tried changing it to manual, tested it again, changed it back to automatic, same behaviour still. I also sent the workbook to a co-worker to test against it being my install/machine, they are experiencing the same issue. I'm going to install excel 2016 and verify that the issue persists there as well.

Comment: @justiceorjustus Doesn't work on 2016 either.

Comment: What data type is coming from SQL for your date?

Comment: @justiceorjustus I have the datatype of `Date` set as 'date' in SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is an issue of Excel not recognizing your data as a date.  Try this cast for your date from SQL:

```
CAST(YourDate AS smalldatetime) "Date"
```

Comment: This worked, apparently the SQL Datatype of `date` doesn't translate well to Excel, however smalldatetime is perfect. I originally had the definition command type set to Table, changing it to SQL and manually selecting every column with some being cast as more Excel-Friendly datatypes worked perfectly!

Comment: @RoflcopterVRoflcopterV Glad to help!